# Change image route to external link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a route that returns a FileResult with an image.

View:

```
<img src="@Url.RouteUrl("HomeProductImage", new { id = Model.ProductId })" />
```

Route to the action:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase("HomeProductImage", "{id}.jpg", new { controller = "Home", 
    action = "ProductImage", id = "" }, new { id = @"\d+" });

public FileResult ProductImage(int id)
{
     // ...
     return File(filename, "image/jpeg");
}
```

How can I change the route, to get an image from another domain, without changing the View?

Eg. instead of domain.com/product/123.jpg -> otherDoamin.com/product/123.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, you should instead write a helper method that returns the full url for your image.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageUrl(this HtmlHelper html, string imageName)
{
    return String.Format("http://somedomain.com/path/to/image/{0}", imageName);
}
```